# Rails not working with apache and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

```html
Listen 81
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.43:81>
  ServerName localhost ServerAlias www.example.com ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost DocumentRoot /home/eze/Appp/public RailsEnv development ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  <Directory "/home/eze/Appp/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hi Iam having the following error when I try to use my rails app from apache and passenger, I am new in apache, I dont now whats going on, help!!

```
An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.
Raw process output:

*** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory (2)
Error ID
3f83f023


Application root
/home/eze/Appp


Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
development


Ruby interpreter command
/usr/bin/ruby


User and groups
uid=1000(eze) gid=1000(eze) groups=1000(eze),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare),128(libvirtd)
```

Comment: It looks like /usr/bin is not the correct location of your ruby executable. What do you get when you type 'which ruby'

Comment: Is your passenger setup correct in your apache virtual hosts? You can add in a specific ruby location. see: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby

Comment: can you add your vhosts entry into your question? eg: `<VirtualHost *:80>...</VirtualHost> `

Comment: This is the output from which ruby  /home/eze/.rbenv/shims/ruby

Comment: There is my virtualhost, by the way I am runnig it localy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this problem but another one emerged. The problem before was that the path waas wrong so que app could not execute the ruby interpreter, but now this is the new problem output

```html
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run: bundle install If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under
a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following: 

Is this app supposed to be run as the eze user? 

Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.


The exception is as follows:
 Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

 /home/eze/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize' /home/eze/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
`map!' /home/eze/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize' /home/eze/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs' /home/eze/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in
`specs_for' /home/eze/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs' /home/eze/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs' /home/eze/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in
`setup' /home/eze/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup' /home/eze/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `
<top (required)>' /home/eze/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require' /home/eze/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require' /home/eze/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in
  `require' /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:263:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code' /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:366:in `running_bundler' /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:261:in
  `run_load_path_setup_code' /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app' /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `
  <module:App>' /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `
    <module:PhusionPassenger>' /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `
      <main>'

Error ID 91901b3a 

Application root /home/eze/Appp Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV) development Ruby interpreter command /home/eze/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby User and groups uid=1000(eze)
        gid=1000(eze) groups=1000(eze),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare),128(libvirtd)
```